# Memory leak in my custom streambuf class

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, iostream

I have a class that derives from std::streambuf. I cannot figure why or where it leaks though; according to the tool I'm using, the last point in my code before it looks is somewhere in this class (but it cannot extract line number)

The idea is that the class can hold any number of streambufs which it will sync data into. (For example, std::cout and a ofstream.rdbuf) I store my data in a string untill I get the std::endl, in which I write to all the streambufs

Can anyone point me to where it could leak memory?

This is my header:

```
#ifndef _MY_STREAM_BUF_H
#define _MY_STREAM_BUF_H

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

#include "../../../Interface/EngineDefs.h"

namespace MyEngine
{
    class MyStreamBuf : public std::streambuf
    {
    public:
        MyStreamBuf();
        ~MyStreamBuf();

        void AddStream(std::streambuf* sb);
        void RemoveStream(std::streambuf* sb);
        bool IsStreamAdded(std::streambuf* sb);

    private:
        std::list<std::streambuf*> mStreamBufs;
        std::string mLine;

        int32_t overflow(int32_t c);
        int32_t sync();

    };
}

#endif
```

cpp file:

```
#include "../../../Include/Core/Logging/MyStreamBuf.h"

namespace MyEngine
{
    MyStreamBuf::MyStreamBuf() : std::streambuf()
    {

    }

    MyStreamBuf::~MyStreamBuf()
    {
        mStreamBufs.clear();
        mLine.clear();
    }

    void MyStreamBuf::AddStream(std::streambuf* sb)
    {
        if (sb)
            mStreamBufs.push_back(sb);
    }

    void MyStreamBuf::RemoveStream(std::streambuf* sb)
    {
        if (sb)
            mStreamBufs.remove(sb);
    }

    bool MyStreamBuf::IsStreamAdded(std::streambuf* sb)
    {
        if (sb)
            return (std::find(mStreamBufs.begin(),mStreamBufs.end(),sb) != mStreamBufs.end());
        else
            return false;
    }

    int32_t MyStreamBuf::overflow(int32_t c)
    {
        int32_t r1 = 0, r2 = 0;

        if (c == EOF)
           return !EOF;
        else
        {
            mLine += c;
            return r1 == EOF || r2 == EOF ? EOF : c;
        }
    }

    int32_t MyStreamBuf::sync()
    {
        int32_t res = 0;

        for(std::list<std::streambuf*>::iterator it = mStreamBufs.begin(); it != mStreamBufs.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (*it)
            {
                (*it)->sputn(mLine.c_str(),mLine.length());
                res &= (*it)->pubsync();
            }
        }               

        mLine.clear();

        return res == 0 ? 0 : -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: is your streamBuf* dynamically allocated? I see a call to remove(), does this perform a delete?

Comment: do you mean mStreambuf member or MyStreamBuf class? the added streambufs are for example std::cout.rdbuf or an ofstream.rdbuf (which I do close and delete)

Comment: I mean whatever is being passed into `void MyStreamBug::RemoveStream(std::streambuf* sb)` is sb dynamically allocated? If so then you should be deleting it as remove just removes the entry and not do the appropriate thing as you are storing pointers, otherwise it maybe better to have a container storing `shared_ptr<std::streambuf*>` instead of raw pointers

Comment: yes, for example a std::ofstream, which I am allocating/deallocating correctly

Comment: where is it being deallocated, I only see a call to `remove()` and no corresponding `delete`? The other thing you could to is to use windbg, enable user stack trace on your app using gflags, then with windbg attach it to your app, enter `.symfix;.reload;!heap -l;` and it should tell you where it thinks the leak is or run your app under visual studio and attach windbg at the point the leaks are detected see http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/detecting-memory-leaks-with-windbg-the-modern-and-free-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't destroying the `streambuf` objects, so it's a classic memory leak.

```
void MyStreamBuf::RemoveStream(std::streambuf* sb)
{
    delete sb; // need this to flush and avoid leak

    if (sb) // do you really need to check if it's null?
        mStreamBufs.remove(sb);
}
```

Note that this isn't really an optimal solution, because having a pointer to a `streambuf` does not imply ownership. For example, `std::cout.rdbuf()` might be something you would add but not something you would want to `delete`. (I don't know what your class is supposed to do.)

You need to decide the ownership semantics. Either `MyStreamBuf` owns all the `mStreamBufs`, or it owns none, or you might add an ownership flag for each, but in any case every owner needs to destroy its objects at some point.

Comment: I should've written it sorry, the class owns none of the streambufs so it should not clean them up

Answer (score -2):

Do you consider that std::streambuf has no virtual destructor? and actually (if you will use dynamic polymorphism) your destructor won't be called
Of course elements of mStreamBufs really not deleted..

Comment: so calling delete on MyStreamBuf, niether ~MyStreamBuf() nor its ~streambuf wont be called?

Comment: `std::basic_streambuf` does have a virtual destructor, see 27.6.3. In fact `std::streambuf` implements no functionality, and could easily have been an abstract base class.

Comment: OK, thanks. Usually I don't use inheritance for standard classes (only decomposition), but in this case it's possible